# How can I get a great view of Shanghai?

Tags: china, vantage-points, shanghai

I'm going to visit Shanghai next month and I know there are several huge skyscrapers.

[image]

**Now I'm wondering from which tower, that's accessible to the main public, can I get the best view at an affordable price?**

Any information about how high up the towers you can get, how crowded they are or long you have to wait and how expensive it would be is welcome.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some of the tallest and most inspiring structures in Asia and the world can be found along the Huangpu River bank in [Pudong](http://wikitravel.org/en/Pudong)'s [Lujiazui](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lujiazui) district.

Three of considerable mention are:

- [Oriental Pearl Tower](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oriental_Pearl_Tower), one of the tallest structures in Asia, providing visitors with [city views](http://www.travelchinaguide.com/attraction/shanghai/oriental_pearl.htm) (different tours available) or light shows (at night) from below (free).
- [Jin Mao Tower](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jin_Mao_Tower), which is a staggering 88-story behemoth. It has an [observation deck](http://www.jinmao88.com/en/jinmao_edifice_tour.htm).
- [Shanghai World Financial Center](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shanghai_World_Financial_Center), the third largest building in Asia and the world, and world's largest by roof height, containing the world's highest [observation deck](http://www.swfc-observatory.com/en/), at 474 m (1555 ft).

Answer (score 12):

Personally the best view is not from those skyscrapers but a nice spot to view these buildings from the bund (Puxi side)

I highly recommend [Three on the bund](http://www.threeonthebund.com/), it has a roof top and now is the perfect time to go. Stunning view of Pudong area.

[image]
<sub>[Image](http://www.flickr.com/photos/stuckincustoms/2089449881/) courtesy of [Stuck in Customs](http://www.flickr.com/photos/stuckincustoms/), licenced under [Creative Commons BY-NC-SA](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/2.0/deed.en)</sub>

Comment: What is it about that view that you like more than from up on the towers? Your answer is making me curious. Btw if you could add a picture of the view, you definitely get a +1 ;-)

Comment: @Ivo Well I grew up in Shanghai, the view from a skyscraper is usually similar (New York, Dubai, Shanghai, Toronto). They are nice, but similar. Skylines, however, vary from city to city. Shanghai by far has the most futuristic view I've seen. [Here's the view you see from threeonbund](http://www.flickr.com/photos/stuckincustoms/2089449881/) Photo by stuck in customs

Answer (score 7):

The Pearl Tower is half museum half observation deck (museum is mostly at the base) but it isn't as tall as the other skyscrapers. The Jin Mao tower has an observation deck and also a bar (I've been to both) the bar as a minimum spend which when I was last there was about 20 quid, personally I like the bar, go up before night is about to fall and drink good whisky/cocktails while the city lights up.

http://www.notworkrelated.co.uk/2011/01/shanghai-7th-dec/

Checkout the photo's on the bottom of that post:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For a **quick but free view** go to the lobby of the Shanghai Grand Hyatt inside the [Jin Mao Tower](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jin_Mao_Tower). It is only on the 54th floor but you get a great view over Pudong, the Pearl river and Shanghai. Dress up as good as you can and then inquire about a room at the reception. You can then linger around in the lobby for a few minutes looking outside the windows.

This may not be the best view in Shanghai but it is a great one and compared to the Shanghai World Financial Center you save $19 USD.

While you are there, take a lift up to the 85th floor and look down the atrium, see the photo in [Dageshi's answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/1723/1317).

Answer (score 3):

You should take the ferry from Osaka (JP) to Shanghai (Or any sea bearing boat that arrives in Shanghai). In the hours prior to arriving in Shanghai the city literally looms on you.